# Reading large number of text files using task (TPL)

Tags: c#

I am reading around 300 txt files using the task concept. My requirement is to read each file , pick the date from every line , check in which week it comes and then compare it with the folder name which are actually the week names (like 41 , 42) whether they both are same or not. if not then write that file name and the line number. As the number of files and the size of files is huge , I am trying to use task concept to that I can speed up the process. Below is my code.

Any help would be appreciated. Thanks in advance.

```
    private void browse_Click(object sender, EventArgs e)
    {
        try
        {
            string newFileName = "";

            DialogResult result = folderBrowserDialog1.ShowDialog();

            if (result == DialogResult.OK)
            {
                DateTime starttime = DateTime.Now;

                string folderPath = Path.GetDirectoryName(folderBrowserDialog1.SelectedPath);

                DirectoryInfo dInfo = new DirectoryInfo(folderPath);

                string[] Allfiles = Directory.EnumerateFiles(folderPath, "*.txt", SearchOption.AllDirectories).ToArray();

                foreach (DirectoryInfo folder in dInfo.GetDirectories())
                {
                    newFileName = "Files_with_duplicate_TGMKT_Names_in_child_Folder_" + folder.Name + ".txt";

                    if (File.Exists(folderPath + "/" + newFileName))
                    {
                        File.Delete(folderPath + "/" + newFileName);
                    }

                    FileInfo[] folderFiles = folder.GetFiles();

                    if (folderFiles.Length != 0)
                    {
                        List<Task> tasks = new List<Task>();
                        foreach (var file in folderFiles)
                        {
                            var task = Task.Factory.StartNew(() =>
                                                        {
                                                            bool taskResult = ReadFile(file.FullName,folderPath,newFileName);
                                                            return taskResult;
                                                        });
                            tasks.Add(task);

                        }

                        Task.WaitAll(tasks.ToArray());
                        DateTime stoptime = DateTime.Now;
                        TimeSpan totaltime = stoptime.Subtract(starttime);
                        label6.Text = Convert.ToString(totaltime);
                        textBox1.Text = folderPath;
                        DialogResult result2 = MessageBox.Show("Read the files successfully.", "Important message", MessageBoxButtons.OK, MessageBoxIcon.Information);
                    }
                }
            }
        }
        catch (Exception)
        {

            throw;
        }
    }

    public bool ReadFile(string file , string folderPath , string newFileName)
    {
        int LineCount = 0;
        string fileName = Path.GetFileNameWithoutExtension(file);

        using (FileStream fs = File.Open(file, FileMode.Open))
        using (BufferedStream bs = new BufferedStream(fs))
        using (StreamReader sr = new StreamReader(bs))
        {
            for (int i = 0; i < 2; i++)
            {
                sr.ReadLine();
            }

            string oline;
            while ((oline = sr.ReadLine()) != null)
            {
                LineCount = ++LineCount;
                string[] eachLine = oline.Split(';');

                string date = eachLine[30].Substring(1).Substring(0, 10);

                DateTime Date = DateTime.ParseExact(date, "d", CultureInfo.InvariantCulture);

                int week = new GregorianCalendar(GregorianCalendarTypes.Localized).GetWeekOfYear(Date, CalendarWeekRule.FirstFourDayWeek, DayOfWeek.Saturday);
                if (Convert.ToString(week) == folderName)
                {

                }
                else
                {
                    using (StreamWriter sw = new StreamWriter(folderPath + "/" + newFileName, true))
                    {
                        Filecount = ++Filecount;
                        sw.WriteLine(fileName + "  " + "--" + "  " + "Line number :" + " " + LineCount);
                    }
                }
            }
        }

        return true;


    }
```

Comment: What .NET version are you using?

Comment: Is there any reason not to use `async`/`await` instead of `Task.Factory.StartNew` and synchronous API?

Comment: no sir , there is no any specific reason. just because i don't know how to use async/await , i use Task.Factory.StartNew

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Your call `MessageBox.Show` inside `ReadFile`, which means every file has to write a message. This way you will get 300 messages.

Try to put your message after the `WaitAll` call outside the `ReadFile` method.

```
                if (files.Length != 0)
                {
                    List<Task> tasks = new List<Task>();
                    foreach (var file in files)
                    {
                        var task = Task.Factory.StartNew(() =>
                                                    {
                                                        bool taskResult = ReadFile(file);
                                                        return taskResult;
                                                    });
                        tasks.Add(task);

                    }
                    Task.WaitAll(tasks.ToArray());
                    // Message here
                    DialogResult result2 = MessageBox.Show("Read the files successfully.", "Important message", MessageBoxButtons.OK, MessageBoxIcon.Information);
                }
```

Comment: you probably shouldn't wait for tasks to finish in the UI thread - the app will appear unresponsive in the mean time

Comment: People on SO should stop trying to infer more requirements than what the OP states. If the OP wants to solve the UI thread later on, let him ask that specific question.

Comment: @LucMorin: it's rather doubtful assertion. IMO, when one sees obvious mistake, why he shouldn't point it? If the solution produces more problems, than it solves, throw away this solution.

Comment: Thanks for your response sir , I tried it and it wrote the filenames along with the line numbers where the date is mismatch. But it is not displaying the messagebox quickly after finishing the reading process. and also the ui is not responsive now , it is not allowing me to browse again.

Comment: try Task.Factory.ContinueWhenAll

Comment: My answer points out that the Message is inside the loop to explain: _"But I am getting the message box so many times. I don't know where I am doing it wrong"_

Comment: Definitely not a good practice to block the UI thread, thanks for pointing it out!

Comment: @DDan : sir I really appreciate your response. I made some changes in my requirement and edited my code. Can you please help me with my new requirement.

Comment: @N2J, as best practice, I would suggest that you stick to a single question so that previous answers can remain relevant. Your new requirements are so different from your original ones that the answer already given becomes out of sync. Please revert your question back, accept the given answer as the solution to your original question, then create a new question specifically for the new requirements. This will make it easier for other people to search the site. Thank you.

Comment: @lucMorin : okay sir, Thanks for valuable time. Sir I created a new question specifically for the new requirement.Can you please help me out there.Thanks.

Comment: I'd just like to point out that blocking the UI might be desirable depending on the context. If you don't block, should the user be allowed to "navigate" away from the current Window/Dialog ? Should UI controls become disabled ? Should the user be allowed to click the "GO" button once again to launch a second instance of the process ? It's easy to say "don't block the UI", but then many answers must be provided as to what is to be allowed while waiting for the long operation to complete.